# Job Titles Capitalization

Tags: writing, capitalization

The rules for the capitalization of job titles are not very clear.

After I've read some internet articles (for instance, this [Capitalization of job title](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107156/capitalization-of-job-title) question) I compiled some rules:

a) It goes before the name of a person:

> **P**rofessor Adams or **D**irector Joe Brown.

b) It goes immediately after the name of the person:

> John Williams, **C**hairman, will attend the meeting.

```
Note: if it has "the", we do not capitalize:
Mrs Smith, the chairwoman of the company x, is retiring.
```

c) In signatures lines at the end of a letter or email:

> Sincerely,
>       
> Sarah Stevens, **P**resident

But then, while browsing a well-known job search website I saw ALL the job titles capitalized in the jobs descriptions:

> We are seeking to recruit an exceptional individual as **O**ffice **M**anager for the Registry team.
>
> We are seeking to appoint a number of **T**eaching **A**ssistants to support pupils' learning and to raise attainment.

and in a common English grammar book I see:

> What do you do?
>   
> I am a **r**eceptionist.

Can somebody explain me the right to way to capitalize a job title?

Comment: Capitalization goes immediately after the name of the person - *No, it does not!* Mr. Mundra, chairperson, will inaugurate the office.

Comment: Further help - http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/capitalization/capitalization-with-job-titles/

Comment: Yes, I had read that article and the rule that you mentioned incorrect is suggested by this article: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/capitalization-of-job-titles.html So, I really don't know what to think. But I will follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm touching whether job titles are capitalized.

[BBC's Learning English Blog](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/learningenglish/2011/11/capitalisation-ii.shtml) describes:

> As a noun *'professor'* **doesn't need** a capital letter, but when it is **someone's title**, like 'Professor Jones' or 'Dr Doolittle' it takes a capital letter.

That said, when you are talking about 'office manager' or teaching assistant' they *don't take* capital letters.

---

Please note that if you have noticed capital letters, be sure that it's not a headline. Because headlines tend to have first letter capital.

Say --

> Title - XYZ Company Needs an Assistant Director

Comment: The reality is that, particularly in job postings, people regularly capitalize job titles to set them apart or emphasize them... That being said, that doesn't mean it's "correct". Similar to the grocer's apostrophe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The article is really helpful as your insights. It seems that actually the capitalization of job titles is straight forward: there are only one or two exceptions to the general lowercasing.

Comment: @Catija Thank you for your comment. You made me understand that when the employees decide to to capitalize job titles in the job descriptions is more a question of utility/style than using the rules of English. This always has confused me.