# What's the proper use of titles in sentences?

Tags: proper-nouns, names

How should one uses titles in sentences?

Should I capitalize the title?

> I talked to General Lee.

or not,

> I talked to general Lee.

And if the name is not mentioned, but I'm talking about the person:

> I talked to the general today.

or,

> I talked to the General today.

Comment: This related question might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68355/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the title appears in front of a name, it must be capitalized:

> General Lee, Doctor Jekyll, Mr. Rochester *(perfectly natural*)

When you use the title by itself in a sentence, it is more normal to leave it uncapitalized:

> I talked to the general today. *(perfectly natural)*

The capitalized variant is also possible, but only if "the General" is some kind of nickname or epithet, which means you can only use it if you *always* refer to that person as "the General."

> I talked to the General today. *(marked but possible)*